# Selenium IDE - Assert that JavaScript redirect worked after clicking Ajax button

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a button that executes an Ajax request and then it successfully redirects to another page.

How do I `assert` that the redirected page was successfully reached?

I have a `clickAndWait` on the button.  But after that..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use verifyTextPresent command to verify a  unique lable or text in the redirected page.by that way you can fix you have successfully  reached the redirected page.

try like this

```
 command : verifyTextPresent                               

 Target  : some unique text in the redirected page.
```

i think your problem can be fixed by this.

Answer (score 0):

IDE has many `assert` commands. You can use any of the one and you can achieve the test scope(here the page is navigated or not).

**Example:**

```
 command :  assertTitle  
 Target :  check the title of the page.
```

In the above he used `verifyTextPresent` it will check weather the text is present or not in the page and it will continue the next step. If you use `assert` commands it will proceed the next step when the assert step is passed. Otherwise it fails.

One thing you keep in mind, selenium won't wait for `Ajax` kind of loading, it will wait for the `Page loading`. So, you have to put `Wait` commands explicitly to finish the Ajax loading.

You can get more`assertions` when you convert the `selenese` code into the `preferred language and testing framework`. You can see that option in the `Option` tab in the IDE.

For more info on [AssertCommands in SIDE](http://qualitytrainings.com/?q=node/33#c111)